# Sitecore - Workbox preview in a pop up

Tags: sitecore

Sitecore Workbox "preview" uses following code which displays it in a different tab,

```
 protected void Preview(string id, string language, string version)
    {
        ...
        Context.ClientPage.SendMessage((object)this, "item:preview(id=" + id + ",language=" + language + ",version=" + version + ")");
    }
```

I want it to appear preview in a popup.
I have already overridden the workbox and it's jsut a matter of modifying this method.
Any ideas how can I change this? I tried different stuff, but nothing worked for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **App_Config\Commands.config** you can find that `item:preview` maps to `Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.PreviewItem` class.

You can create your own command basing on the **PreviewItem** class and use it instead of the `item:preview` command.

If you reflect the code of **PreviewItem** class you'll see the **Run** method which executes

```
SheerResponse.Eval("window.open('" + (object) webSiteUrl + "', '_blank')");
```

at the very end of this method. This loads the preview in a new tab. Change this logic to whatever you need in your overriden class.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the answer, it was really helpful.
Actually I wanted to open up the content editor in a new tab. 
I have reflected some commands like preview, open and understood what's going on internally.

And I have overridded the "Open" mwthod in the workbox as follows to open the content editor item in the new tab,

```
...
UrlString urlString = new UrlString("/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Editor");

        urlString.Append("id", id);
        urlString.Append("vs", version);
        urlString.Append("ro", sectionId);
        urlString.Append("la", language);
        urlString.Append("fo", id);

        SheerResponse.Eval("window.open('" + (object)urlString + "', '_blank')");
...
```

It works!!!!!
Thanks again.